How can I use pipreqs in virtual environment
I have installed pipreqs moudle in python global path. and I can use it if I don't activate any venv. however when I activate an venv, pipreqs command can't use with "module not found" error.
I can't understand the reason. if a module didn't found in venv, why python don't seek it in global path?
below is some outputs may be useful for the issue.
deactive the venv.
➜  python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/Users/levyk/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/pipreqs',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python312.zip',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/levyk/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/levyk/Library/Python/3.12' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/levyk/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True

activate the venv:
(.venv) ➜  lab python -m site      
sys.path = [
    '/Users/levyk/Project/Python/lab',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python312.zip',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/levyk/Project/Python/lab/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/levyk/Library/Python/3.12' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/levyk/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False


This question is similar to: How to use external libraries with virtualenv?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As far as I understood, for pipreqs to do what it is meant to do, it has to be installed in the environment to be investigated. I doubt installing pipreqs globally makes much sense.


if a module didn't found in venv, why python don't seek it in global path?

One idea behind using virtual environments is to make sure that only specific modules and versions of said modules are used. Thus the default setting in venv is to not use any globally installed libraries, see here in the documentation.
For your question on how to use it I would suggest to take a look at other answers here at Stack Overflow like this one: How to use external libraries in venv.
